# using rescue with bang method or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i see lot of books who uses bang method like `create!` or `save!` but they don't use *rescue* block to catch exceptions, for example if i take a block of code from ruby on rails tutoriel book :

```
def follow!(other user)
 relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
end
```

here michael hartl use follow with ! , and bang method create! without rescue exception, some one can explain to me when i should use bang method and does it necessary to add rescue to it ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already know that bang methods(`create!` etc) will raise an error whereas plain methods(`create`)  will not. your question is which should be used where. Well, it boils down to personnel preference where is no one right way. but generally the rails codebases(including the default code generated by rails) seem to follow this

**plain methods in Controllers**

```
def create
 @post = Post.new
 @post = params[:posts]
 if @post.save 
    #success, redirect_to  new post & set succcess flash 
 else
    #failure, render new action again with errors 
end
```

**Bang methods in tests**

```
it "creates a new post" do
   p = Post.create! :title => '' #auto raise an error on validation failure             
   p.should do_something
end
```

so In my Humble Opinion, you should not use bang methods in your controllers. If you do, please handle them gracefully so that user gets a helpful error message which says what went wrong, how to fix it instead of rails famous "*Something went wrong*" error 500 page.

Comment: thank you this is helpful but i have juste one question, in production if i use bang method without rescue like the block of code in my question , does rails automatically show you a page with famous sentence "Somethig went wrong" or it show you a page with detail errors for this exception ?

Comment: @medBo: in development you get details. In production: red message

Answer (score 2):

I have a general rule: if I dont expect a `create` or `save` etc to fail, I use the bang version. If it never fails, it makes no difference, if it however fails sometime, due to a bug or corrupt data, then

1. I get notified (via airbrake)
2. I can prevent database corruption (via transaction rollback). Otherwise a `save` might fail sometime, unexpectedly, and you'll notice it maybe months later

Comment: but you don't answered my question :(

Comment: if you expect the `save` to fail, you can either use the bang version and rescue the exception, or use the normal version and check for true / false, i think the latter is the more elegant way, but it's a matter of taste. you have to ask yourself "do i expect a failure, and how do i handle it". if you expect it, you __have__ to handle it.

Comment: you say that you can prevent database corruption (via transaction rollback), where you place the code of rollback ? in rescue block ? and why a lot of books don't use rescue when they use save! and create! ...

Comment: usually in the controller using around filters. you rescue exceptions, rollback and then re-raise